# Jquery animation to remove a popup error message - Beginner

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this  tag which will only appear when the action the user performed is success.

It's only suppose to be displayed for a few seconds and then vanish.

```
<div class="alert alert-success" role="alert">
  Yes. <a href="#" class="alert-link">. You have registered successfully</a>
</div>
```

How can i write a Jquery method that will do this animation for me ?

Comment: You don't write such a method, you use `animate();`

Comment: My fav message plugin: http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-message/

Answer (score 1):

Simply use the delay function, like this:

```
$( "#foo" ).delay( 5000 ).fadeOut( 400 );
```

Where "foo" is the id of your div.

Just as easy as that!

Here is a JSFiddle:

[JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/74yBt/2/)

Comment: For some reason this is not working for me. It's not getting animated at all

Comment: What kind of browser do you use?

Comment: Chrome. I have bootstrap installed, and its not working for me

Comment: When I try in chrome it works. Just open the page and wait for 5 seconds, or did you do that already ?

Comment: try this new fiddle, I edited the post. I also made it in a way, you can call it on your alter-fail pop up as well, as long as you give them the ID's

Comment: It appears but, it doesn't fade away. The animation won't work

Comment: Do you also have another browser than the one you are currently using?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/57212/discussion-between-jifus-and-illep).

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$(".alert-success").slideDown();
setTimeout(function() {
    $(".alert-success").slideUp();
}, 5000);
```

5000 (miliseconds) means 5 seconds to be shown

Comment: What hapence if i want to have the above method for both `.alter-success` and `.alter-fail`. How should i write it

Comment: I think you would use this method in different parts of your code, so you have to replicate it and change de selector to "alert-fail"

Comment: Can you also show me how to write the HTMl part of it. For some reason its not working on mine.

Comment: @Illep
 `<div class="alert alert-error" role="alert">
        No. <a href="#" class="alert-link">. You have not registered successfully</a>
    </div>`